# Should I use cyclomatic complexity in React?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-functional-component, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm working on a React application using functional components. The lint configuration file has [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity) enabled. That means that every component or custom hook that has too many logical conditions is marked with an error.

Cyclomatic Complexity is meant to work per function and works well on class components but it doesn't recognize a functional component or custom hook as a set of different functions, so it's very easy to go over the complexity limit and I have to add a lot of `eslint-disable-next-line complexity` comments.

The project has API and utils functions where the Cyclomatic Complexity is useful.

Is there a standard way to use Cyclomatic Complexity in React applications? Or should I just give up using it?

*For reference*: sonar-js has added an [exception to the *Cognitive Complexity* rule for React functional components](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/2238). Not sure it's the same thing although it looks very similar.

Comment: Interesting topic. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any resource...
Considering the limitation you've reported, if I'd end up disabling that rule on multiple occasions, then I'd probably not use that rule at all